# Flickering before page transition

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to get a proper page transition in Ionic 4 but before clicking the page gets white and after some delay the actual transition begins. This looks very weird to the users. Does anyone had the same issues and can help me with this?

https://youtu.be/gmjyCkYPlFQ

I already tried to figure out why this happens but actually I don't have any listeners on those pages and this issue happens on every page so this is really strange. Directly in the browser I cannot reproduce it (or it is so fast that I don't recognize) but there I cannot see the problem.

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('tabs', {replaceUrl: true});
```

Node: 10

Ionic: 4.12.0